# Are user variables enabled in shared hosting?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do a query that uses a user variable.  E.g:

```
SELECT Id,userId,rank
FROM
  (SELECT Id,userID,
     @rank := IFNULL(@rank,0)+1 as rank
  FROM users
  ORDER BY food_total DESC) AS T
WHERE T.userID = 'g02'
```

Could someone shed some light on whether such a query can be run on any shared hosting by default (i.e without requesting the hoster to enable it (if it is something that needs to be activated)

Alternatively, is there a way to do the query without using a user variable?

Comment: *is there a way to do the query without using a user variable?* Yes. But if server version is below 8 the query needs in unique field/expression existence, and it will be expensive (especially when the source table is huge). *whether such a query can be run on any shared hosting by default* Yes. But I recommend you to use explicit variable initialization (in FROM clause, not in an expression). PS. The value calculated in `rank` field is really ROW_NUMBER, not RANK...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things to fix; see comments:

```
SELECT  Id, userId, rank
    FROM  (
        SELECT  Id, userID, @rank := @rank + 1 as rank
            FROM  users
            ORDER BY  food_total DESC
            LIMIT 9999999   -- Trick it into not throwing away the ORDER BY
          ) AS T
    JOIN  ( SELECT @rank := 0 ) AS r    -- Initialize @rank
    WHERE  T.userID = 'g02'
```

This seems to depend on the Optimizer to do the simple subquery (with the initialization) first.

The initialization could be done as a separate statement (either `SET` or `SELECT`).

An important note is that values of @ variables last until the connection is closed.

Back to your question:  I know of no way to disable user variables.

Comment: No. I mean ``... (SELECT  Id, userID, @rank := @rank+1 as `rank` FROM users, (SELECT @rank := 0) var ORDER BY ...``. Documentation do not tell us when the variable is created/initialized - when parsed or when needed for the first time during execution. So a subquery `T` may be already executed when subquery `r` execution starts...

Comment: @Akina Would it be okay if you let me know your alternative by showing me the sql rather than describing it (I'm bad at understanding)? :)

Comment: I simplified my Answer a little.  I don't think Akina's suggestion will work -- because the entire list needs to be scanned to get "rank", then extract that one row

Comment: @Rick James Thanks, Rick.